# this really just nails it

Tags: word-usage

> The findings strongly suggest that fast radio bursts could be the result of at least two distinct astrophysical phenomena. “I think **this really just nails it** that there is a difference,” says study co-author Kiyoshi Masui, an astrophysicist at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology in Cambridge.

Source: [nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01560-4)

What does "this" refer to? It is singular, not consistent with whatever previously mentioned ("the findings" and "bursts" are plural).  Perhaps it refers to "the result" - "the result has successfully hit the target"? Just a wild guess.

Comment: You haven't provided enough context to tell us what ***this*** refers to, but probably it's just a vague general reference to ***this study, this** [review of the] **findings***. The fact that ***findings*** is plural doesn't mean that can't be what "this" refers to - if that's what was meant, a native speaker would be far more likely to use ***this*** than ***these*** anyway.

Comment: "this" = "the findings"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **it** that is "being nailed" in the quote is a [*dummy it*](https://www.thoughtco.com/dummy-it-in-grammar-1690414). The **this** in the quote could also be interpreted as a *dummy it*, or as an implied reference to "the discovery" in a general sense.

There is no reason that the pronoun has to refer to "the findings" or "the result" mentioned in the previous sentence, because it is a quote of something said by a person, not the actual words of the author who wrote the article.

Comment: Thank you.   So "this really just nails it" means "the discovery really precisely offers the information we have long awaited for?"

Comment: @NewPlanet I'm not sure where you're getting "precisely" but yes, that's the gist of it.

Comment: Where I got "precisely":  just ->exactly ->precisely.   Why is it puzzling?

Comment: @NewPlanet I would say that in the quote "just" is used as an intensifier rather than to mean "exactly" or "precisely."